# Knotes not showing notes in it after rebooting

Tags: notes

I've installed Knotes version 5.13.3 into Ubuntu 20.04 and I've added 7 notes to it. Whenever I reboot I lose all the notes I have added. What must I do to prevent this?

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/share/akonadi
total 32 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stevelilley stevelilley 7129 Dec 30 09:13 Akonadi.error
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stevelilley stevelilley 140 Dec 30 09:08 Akonadi.error.old 
drwxrwxr-x 6 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 30 09:08 db_data 
drwxrwxr-x 2 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 26 09:20 db_misc 
drwxrwxr-x 2 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 26 09:20 file_db_data 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stevelilley stevelilley 3660 Dec 26 09:20 mysql.conf
drwxrwxr-x 8 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 26 09:20 search_db 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stevelilley stevelilley 22 Dec 30 09:08 socket-stevelilley-Precision-7520-default -> /run/user/1000/akonadi
```

Comment: This maybe permissions issue. Please show the output of `ls -l ~/.local/share/akonadi` .

Comment: ls -l ~/.local/share/akonadi
total 32
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stevelilley stevelilley 7129 Dec 30 09:13 Akonadi.error
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stevelilley stevelilley  140 Dec 30 09:08 Akonadi.error.old
drwxrwxr-x 6 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 30 09:08 db_data
drwxrwxr-x 2 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 26 09:20 db_misc
drwxrwxr-x 2 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 26 09:20 file_db_data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stevelilley stevelilley 3660 Dec 26 09:20 mysql.conf
drwxrwxr-x 8 stevelilley stevelilley 4096 Dec 26 09:20 search_db
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stevelilley stevelilley   22 Dec 30 09:08 socket-

Comment: stevelilley-Precision-7520-default -> /run/user/1000/akonadi

Comment: @Steve L Food for thought...I stopped using knotes when I realised that some of my notes contained important information, and that it is unclear how I would restore them from a backup if that became necessary. Or indeed what files need to be backed up. Now I have a Notes folder with my notes in text files, the title of each file is the title of the note. Can sort, search etc using usual tools and display on screen with a little text editor window. Not as pretty maybe but much more transparent regarding where my data is.

Comment: The issue I had with Notes is that it doesn't have a system tray facility where if you click on it, notes will pop up immediately. Up to 18.04 I had been using Tomboy where it had that facility but it no longer is available in 20.04. I found Knotes has it but I have the issue I have is it does not remembering my notes after a reboot.

Comment: Same issue here... I lost important information that stored on a note. KDE can't be more buggy than it is today.

I am removing all their software and moving on to gnome alternatives, which at least they do the jobs as they are expected to.